# shell scripts that's ends when the caller script end

Tags: bash, shell, exec, screen, systemd

I have two scripts:
/mnt/tmp/a.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello >> /tmp/a.sh.log
i=0
/mnt/tmp/b.sh &

while [[ $i -lt "5" ]]
do
        echo "seconde : $i " >> /tmp/a.sh.log
        sleep 1
        i=$(($i+1))
done
```

and /mnt/tmp/b.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello >> /tmp/b.sh.log
i=0

while [[ $i -lt "10" ]]
do
        echo "seconde : $i " >> /tmp/b.sh.log
        sleep 1
        i=$(($i+1))
done
```

when I manually start /mnt/tmp/a.sh here are the outputs files:
/tmp/a.sh.log

```
hello
seconde : 0
seconde : 1
seconde : 2
seconde : 3
seconde : 4
```

and /tmp/b.sh.log

```
hello
seconde : 0
seconde : 1
seconde : 2
seconde : 3
seconde : 4
seconde : 5
seconde : 6
seconde : 7
seconde : 8
seconde : 9
```

but when /mnt/tmp/a.sh is called during system startup, here are the outputs files:

/tmp/a.sh.log

```
hello
seconde : 0
seconde : 1
seconde : 2
seconde : 3
seconde : 4
```

and /tmp/b.sh.log
hello

```
seconde : 0
seconde : 1
seconde : 2
seconde : 3
seconde : 4
```

When /mnt/tmp/a.sh ends all the scripts that were launched by it in the background (using &) ends!

the a.sh script is called at the boot by /usr/bin/custom-script:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "===========================================" > /tmp/start
echo "        custom script                      " >> /tmp/start
echo "===========================================" >> /tmp/start

mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt
/mnt/tmp/a.sh
```

this custom-script is configured by /lib/systemd/system/custom-script.service as:

```
[Unit]
Description=start custom script at boot

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/custom-script'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am working in an SOM board imx6 using a yocto based system.

**Already tried solutions:**

all this versions of /mnt/tmp/a.sh gives the same problem:

using exec:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello >> /tmp/a.sh.log
i=0
(exec /mnt/tmp/b.sh )&

while [[ $i -lt "5" ]]
do
        echo "seconde : $i " >> /tmp/a.sh.log
        sleep 1
        i=$(($i+1))
done
```

using source:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello >> /tmp/a.sh.log
i=0
source /mnt/tmp/b.sh &

while [[ $i -lt "5" ]]
do
        echo "seconde : $i " >> /tmp/a.sh.log
        sleep 1
        i=$(($i+1))
done
```

using nohup:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello >> /tmp/a.sh.log
i=0
nohup /mnt/tmp/b.sh > /var/log/nohup.log & # I used /var/log/nohup.log because my system is read-only:nohup: can't open '/home/root/nohup.out': Read-only file system 

while [[ $i -lt "5" ]]
do
        echo "seconde : $i " >> /tmp/a.sh.log
        sleep 1
        i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Can someone help here?

Comment: try using [`nohup`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)

Comment: @DigvijayS same problem with nohup !

Comment: @azeddinebenomar : I don't quite understand your question. From the ouput you posted, a.sh runs the same, whether started at boot time or not. It seems that you get different outputs from b.sh, but you did not explain how you started the two cases from b.sh; so the differences are in `b`, not in `a`.

Comment: @user1934428 the b.sh is started from inside a.sh (line 5)

Comment: I see. But you start the b in the background. You should at least wait until the end of the `a` until the `b` is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolve the problem:

the service file for systemd of the custom-script should have type=forking not type=simple:

/lib/systemd/system/custom-script.service

```
[Unit]
Description=start custom script at boot

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/custom-script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

thank you!